# Nearest Shops Feature by using Google Places API

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places

I am trying to develop the feature in my website to search the nearest Stores for the given location/address.
For example.
http://www.tesco.com/store-locator/uk/

After I have done some research, I think, I need to use the Google Places API to locate the nearest places.  I have tested with some examples and it's working.

However, I don't know how to upload my chain of stores onto the Google Map and how to find the nearest stores (**only mine, not other stores**).  I couldn't find a feature to upload my places onto the Google Places by using their API.

Could you please guide me how I could achieve it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am attempting a similar feature.

First, you will need to upload your business locations to google. I think this is an important step it getting your places to show up on google maps. You can do that here: https://www.google.com/local/manage/#/list

After uploading you can download all of the locations in csv format. Once you have all of your locations in csv format you can parse the data and create a list of addresses to search.

Once you have your addresses you can use google's distance matrix api https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/

you can search up to 100 places and get back a distance result for each location. Finally you can parse the distance results to find the closest location.

A few drawbacks here. There is a URL length limit of 2000 characters. If you are searching a lot of places this will fill up fast. Also, the free version of the API has a limit of 100 places per search and a maximum of 100 places per 10 seconds so if you have a lot of places or a lot of users this will be an issue.

Comment: I ran into issues with the URL length limit and decided to use a service to generate a map for me.
http://batchgeo.com/